# SQLite Implementation in VS 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, visual-studio-2019, gac

I'm still really new to coding and trying to make my first WPF application. I have been trying to implement sqlite for the past like 3 days now.

I am using VS 2019. I have downloaded the SQLite Toolbox and am following the instructions here -  https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider. I did a full installation. Was I supposed to install it in my project directory? Because now I just have a bunch of files and nothing seems to have changed in Studio. I tried using Install.exe, but it returned a "confirm option not enabled" error. Looking at a similar question, I tried putting the files in an external folder in my project, and then installed the System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll to my GAC using the VS Dev Console. The toolbox doesn't see any changes, and does not recognize the dll and I'm having a hard time finding reliable information for my version. Thanks for any help getting pointed in the right direction!

Comment: I'd recommend installing a SQLite Nuget package into your project instead. Look under "Tools\NuGet Package Manager\Manage Nuget Packages for Solution …"  menu tree. Then search for SQLite. There's many to choose from even a Microsoft Entity Framework implementation of SQLite

Comment: If you're just after a simple means of storing data you could choose one of the PCL Net packages. I recently used SQLite-net-pcl  by Frank Krueger for a Xamarin app. It allows for easy storage of class types.

Comment: I guess I'm just not totally sure what I "need" to make it work. It will be a ERP system, with lots of forms and data entry. I just need it to see the Database, I had made previous attempts with the nugets and I got an insertion - could not find table error. I created a class with the connection and used Environment for the path. No errors other than that, just isn't talking to me! I read that it could be related to Interoper dlls, but I'm confused about what I need after thinking I needed this toolbox, then the dll, some Nugets.

Comment: Are you able to post up any simplified DBConnection, data file and file creation code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you mention toolbox as far as I'm aware you access the SQLite functionality programmatically.

The NuGet packages that I recently used for a Xamarin project (SQLite-net-pcl by Frank Krueger and supporting libraries) allowed me to use pretty simple object mapping without recourse to SQL like strings.

I use a lot of interfaces in my code, but here's my all access database class

```
:

   public class AllAccessDataTableBaseSqLite<T> : IDataAccessRead<T>, IDataAccessWrite<T>,IDataAccessExpressionSearch<T>, IDataAccessDelete<T> where T: IDataRecord, new()
    {
        //Note that this static value will only apply to those classes based on the same generic type e.g. all DataTableBase<User> instances etc.
        public static SQLiteAsyncConnection DBConnection;

        /// <summary>
        /// Lock object to prevent multi-thread interruption of code segment.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly object CollisionLock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public AllAccessDataTableBaseSqLite()
        {
            lock (CollisionLock)
            {
                if (DBConnection != null)
                {
                    DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();

                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    string directory;

                    if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Unknown)
                    {
                        directory = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        directory = "DataStore";
                        var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                        directory = directoryInfo.FullName;
                    }

                    var path = Path.Combine(directory, $"{typeof(T).Name}.db");
                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using var fileStream = File.Create(path);

                        fileStream.Close();
                    }

                    DBConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
                    DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the data table
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<CreateTableResult> CreateTableAsync()
        {
            if (DBConnection != null)
            {
                return await DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
            }

            return CreateTableResult.Migrated;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new record entry
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Data entity to enter</param>
        /// <param name="user">Current User information</param>
        /// <returns>New entry record if successful</returns>
        public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity, IUserRecord user)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.CreatedByUserId = user.Id;
            entity.Id = 0;
            try
            {
                await DBConnection.InsertAsync(entity);

            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                if (e.Message == "Constraint")
                {
                    throw new InvalidConstraintException(e.Message, e.InnerException);
                }
            }            
            var result = entity;

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update a collection of new entities of type T to the data table.
        /// All entities should be present within the data table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityList">Entity collection</param>
        /// <param name="user">user making the change</param>
        /// <returns>ID of entities successfully updated or added</returns>
        public async Task<int> UpdateAllAsync(IEnumerable<T> entityList, IUserRecord user)
        {
            var result = 0;
            foreach (var t in entityList)
            {
                if (null != await UpdateAsync(t, user))
                {
                    result++ ;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtain the data record with the given Id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id value to select the record by</param>
        /// <returns>A valid record if found otherwise null</returns>
        public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return await DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function returns all database entries that are not marked deleted or changed
        /// Warning: The data set may be very large
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list of entries</returns>
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
        {
            if (DBConnection != null)
            {
                return await DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(x=>x.ChangedDate==default && x.DeletedDate==default)
                    .ToListAsync();

            }
            return new List<T>();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllHistoric() => await DBConnection.Table<T>().ToListAsync();


        /// <summary>
        /// This function is used to update the supplied record entry within the database.
        /// If the supplied record does not have a non-zero value Id field it is assumed to be a
        /// new record to be inserted into the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Record to update</param>
        /// <param name="user">User performing the action</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity, IUserRecord user)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            var newRecord = (T) ((entity) as BaseRecord<T>)?.Clone();

            if (null == newRecord)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            //if Id is zero assume that the record is new and to be added
            if (newRecord.Id == 0)
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    newRecord.CreatedByUserId = user.Id;
                }
                newRecord.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                newRecord.Id = await DBConnection.InsertAsync(newRecord);
                return newRecord;
            }

            // Id is not zero and thus a new record should be created linked to the old record.
            var oldRecord = await GetById(newRecord.Id);
            oldRecord.ChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (user != null)
            {
                oldRecord.ChangedByUserId = user.Id;
            }
            try
            {
                var result = await DBConnection.UpdateAsync(oldRecord);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

               Debug.WriteLine($"UpdateAsync {e.Message}");
            }           

            newRecord.PreviousRecordId = oldRecord.Id;
            newRecord.Id = 0;

            return await CreateAsync(newRecord, user);

        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<int> DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return await DBConnection.DeleteAsync(entity);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task DeleteAll()
        {
            await DBConnection.DropTableAsync<T>();
            await CreateTableAsync();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<PagedResult<T>> GetAllPagedResult(int recordId, uint maxResults = 100)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            List<T> list;

            if (maxResults == 0)
            {
                list = await GetAll();
            }
            else
            {
                list = await DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(x => (x.Id >= recordId && x.ChangedDate == default && x.DeletedDate == default)).ToListAsync();
                if (list.Count() > maxResults)
                {
                    list = list.GetRange(0, (int) maxResults);
                }
            }

            return new PagedResult<T>(list, list.Count());

        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsyncOrdered<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
            Expression<Func<T, TValue>> orderBy = null)
        {
            var query = DBConnection.Table<T>();
            if (predicate != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(predicate);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = query.OrderBy<TValue>(orderBy);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<T> FindFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) => await DBConnection.FindAsync(predicate);
    }
```

I'm using data classes based upon:

```
public interface IDataRecord 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifier for record
    /// </summary>
    int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Link to previous version of record
    /// </summary>
    int PreviousRecordId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Identity that made the change
    /// </summary>
    int ChangedByUserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date when the data record was last changed
    /// </summary>
    DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identity of User that deleted the record
    /// </summary>
    int DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date when the data record was deleted
    /// </summary>
    DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identity of User that created the record
    /// </summary>
    int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date when the data record was added
    /// </summary>
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    object Clone();
}
```

Obviously you don't have to use this, but put simply for my application implementation each type of data record is stored in its own data file (thus 1 table per file) and this is created at the beginning in the constructor.

- The SQLite db connection is created using the data file path.
- Table is created using the dbconnection

**edit**

I've had a closer look at your code.
Points to note are:

- You don't appear to be creating a table.
- Access to non-app folders is restricted if you chose to create a UWP rather than base WPF project - be aware of folder access permissions when running apps especially in release mode.

Comment: I had to redo everything I had done because I got frustrated and restarted. I still can't get my database to do anything, I'm not getting any errors this time around. But it is still not working. I am trying to post code for you to review but I am new and it won't let me post hardly anything. Can I email you the file? I defined a class for the table I want to make. I made a public partial class which references my db location. I made a button, but I can't figure out what commands I'm needing to use. I opened the connection but I don't know how to insert the values from the class I made.

Comment: I have pasted some of my code here. If you need more, let me know. I am beyond confused at this point. https://pastebin.com/rLfVT5BH

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay - I've pasted some code https://pastebin.com/3JyNT765, from a working WPF .NET 4.7.2 app - it uses the latest C# and `SQLite-net-pcl` by SQLite-net v1.7.335 NuGet package. The app just has two buttons on the default MainWindow one triggers the creation of a new user the other gets a list of all users in the database. In the current form it runs synchronously, but Id suggest that you look at making it asynchronous (using `async Task` types and `SQLiteAsyncConnection`).